# How to define routing for (controllers / methods) in 2 projects defined in one solution in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-mvc-routing

I created two project but I can't call something
like this for second one (WebApplication8) :

```
https://localhost:44356/api/Students/getData?stdId=5
```

This url worked for my first/main project (ContosoUniversity)

How to define routing for both project's controller in  on solution

[image: image note]

Answer (score 1):

Create area for main project and define routing for each one.